# C++: Компилятор не подставляет функцию в шаблон

Tags: c++

При подстановке функции в шаблон, компилятор почему-то её не видит.
Хотя двумя строчками выше видит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <endian.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename RESULT_T, typename letoh_func, typename T> 
static RESULT_T compose_high_low(T high, T low)
{
    RESULT_T res = letoh_func(high);
    res <<= sizeof(T) * 8;
    res |= letoh_func(low);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    uint16_t k = le16toh(1);
    uint16_t high = 1, low = 2;
    uint32_t n = compose_high_low<uint32_t, le16toh>(high, low); // error: 'le16toh' was not declared in this scope
    cout << hex << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Запустить тут: http://cpp.sh/7w7afl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`le16toh` часто является макросом. А чтобы передать в качестве параметра шаблона указатель на функцию, необходимо использовать параметр не-тип. И вообще, используйте `boost::endian`.

```
#include <boost/endian/conversion.hpp>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename x_Result, typename x_Value>
static x_Result compose_high_low(x_Value const high, x_Value const low) noexcept
{
    x_Result res{::boost::endian::little_to_native(high)};
    res <<= sizeof(x_Value) * CHAR_BIT;
    res |= ::boost::endian::little_to_native(low);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << ::std::hex
    << compose_high_low<::std::uint32_t>(::std::uint16_t{1}, ::std::uint16_t{2})
    << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В общем, ясно, функция le16toh на самом деле - макрос, поэтому компилятор так и реагирует.
К сожалению, мы не используем в проекте boost. Но спасибо за верный ответ.
Вот решение, подходящее мне: http://cpp.sh/2s4bq